# Permanently highlight all occurrences of a specific keyword

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, resharper

I'm editing a hugh Javascript file. For better orientation, it would be cool if I could change the style of all `function` keywords (not changing the style of all other keywords).

Can this be done in VS 2012 with Resharper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's acutally not so hard to write a VS extension that does that or similar things. See templates etc. here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885242.aspx

I'll mark this as the accepted answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can do this without ReSharper. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>, type "function", press <kbd>enter</kbd> and don't close find window. All occurences of word
"function" will be highlighted and you can continue your editing. When you close find windows, highlighting will be gone.